# how to add and remove action bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Navigation Drawer activity requires action bar to run. but i want my splash art and login activity to have no action bar. my application stops responding when i tested this code out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeboy.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"> 
</activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can hide toolbar from specific activity by following code.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
    OR 
    getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.hide();

    OR
   getActionbar().hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different Style for SplashScreen Activity in the Style.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And include that style to your splash activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
</activity>
```